# Some queries about Blogger SEO

Tags: seo, blogger

I have been using Blogger from past 2 years and happy with it.

Recently I read many articles saying WordPress is far more better than Google Blogger in terms of SEO.  That can be true to some extent.

But what I think is if you have good content and SEO optimization, your blog and site will get higher rank irrespective of your using WordPress or Blogger.

**What can I do to improve my Blogger's rank?**

I have been reading SEO articles from last 2 weeks and thinking of implementing some of the things in my next post.

I am implementing following things for better SEO. I would love if someone would correct me if I am making any mistakes.

1.Titles are important and the URL too. Blogger allows 40 characters in
   URL that's why I post the title with keywords in it and then I re-post
   it with the actual title I want users to see.

For example: if my post is about "Best outfits" I will post with title
   "worlds best women men outfits clothing"  which has keywords and
   Blogger will create url like `www.xyz.blogspot.com/06/11/worlds-latest
   -best-women-men-outfits`

Then I can re-post it with new user readable title "World's Best Outfits
   For Men & Women, Latest Trends in Outfits"

1. The first 200 words of the post are important, so I try to use the
   relevant important keywords at the beginning of post. But keyword
   stuffing can get my blog de-indexed from Google, so I try to make
   sentences from the keywords. For example I am writing about iPhone. I
   would use following line  to start my post

   *"Article about iPhone, iPhone's release date, its features
   functions & price. Is Galaxy s2 better than iPhone 4"*

   I am not sure if it is right or wrong ethically.
2. I try to give links of my another post at the starting of my current
   post or ending of my post. I have read somewhere that links
   containing keywords are weighted higher in search engines and search
   engines give more  importance to starting and ending of the post.
3. I try using keywords in the whole post whenever it is possible,
   Around 7-8 times. I take care that I'm not stuffing keywords
   unnecessarily.
4. I use 4-5 labels(tags) for every post containing keywords and I show labels
   just before the post and after the post.
5. I keep at least 10 posts on my home page and label cloud and blog
   archive too.
6. SEO experts say Use `H2` tags for important keywords & titles. I am not sure, but does
   it really help? 
   I try to put titles in `H2` or `H3` tags and if I am
   using titles inside the post I try to use `H2` tags for it.

Comment: John Conde♦: i dont know but it seems like u enjoy closing questionss ? This question was very specific and different from other questions. The link you have given is of NO use..make sure if you provide link which have proper answer.

Comment: I do not "enjoy" closing questions. This question was not closed because an answer was posted elsewhere. It was closed because you are asking the same question as the one marked as a duplicate. SE sites do not allow the same question to be asked over and over again. Once is enough as any question can be improved and answered at any time.